# Using Maven in Google App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-2

I'm making Google App Engine project with SpringSource Tool Suite. I made project without maven and added libraries to lib folder and I got Spring Framework work perfectly. But the I tried to make project that uses Maven, adn I when I tried to run my app on development server it cannot find any classes.

So what should I do, so that my dependecies are actually deployed to lib folder?

Example of dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [pom.xml](https://github.com/taylorleese/google-app-engine-jappstart/blob/master/pom.xml) in my jappstart project. It's a functional GAE project that uses Spring.

Comment: what I always find strange about these configurations (maven in general) is that you have some base package (term I made up myself) like com.google.dominator for some imaginary application dominiator by com.google. Is your groupId them com.google and your artifactId dominator? Or, what would be the 'base package' in your pom.xml? So the longest string of packages for which each parent has only one child. Is it com.jappstart.jappstart-web?

Comment: In any case, the pom.xml seems very usefull, so in any case, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [example](http://www.ensor.cc/2007/12/welcome-to-my-blog.html) it covers Sprint 3, Google App Engine and maven.